# Accessing custom Toolbar using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, pyqt, toolbar

I created a toolbar in a plugin with:

```py
toolbar = iface.addToolBar("new Toolbar")
```

I know I can toggle visibility of this toolbar with:

```py
toolbar.setVisible(False)
```

and

```py
toolbar.setVisible(True)
```

But for that I need direct access to the Variable toolbar

Now I want to write a new plugin which changes visibility of some toolbars.

From the new toolbar i cant access the variable toolbar.

So I tried to access the Toolbar with

```py
iface.mainWindow().findChild(QToolBar, 'new Toolbar')
```

But it only returns None. I also don't have a Tooltip when I hover over the Toolbar. QGIS Standard Toolbars show a Tooltip on Hover...

It seems the Name of the toolbar isn't really saved.

How can I define a Name for a toolbar, so I can access it later from other scripts or is there a way to access it with 'new Toolbar'?

Also it would be nice to find identifiers for accessing toolbars of third party plugins I installed for QGIS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the PyQt method :

```py
toolbar.setObjectName("new Toolbar")
```

now, the following :

```py
iface.mainWindow().findChild(QToolBar,'new Toolbar')
```

will return an object, your toolbar.

Or, if you want to search the toolbar by its window title, set at its instanciation, you can do :

```py
searched_toolbars = [
    t for t in iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QToolBar)
    if t.windowTitle() == "new Toolbar"
]

if len(searched_toolbars) > 0:
    my_toolbar = searched_toolbars[0]
```